# Error writing ORC file from spark to hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, orc

I'm doing a project for school on a provided small cluster (4 nodes, 1 is namenode and spark master). I'm doing the calculation and then write the spark DataFrame to hadoop as ORC file. I then get below error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/myfile.orc/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180521123532_0005_m_000010_3/part-00010-1dd484de-2d33-4a51-8029-737aa957264e-c000.snappy.orc could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 3 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

And somewhat hidden in the stack trace:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column has wrong number of index entries found: 0 expected: 36
```

total data set is 50 million rows. if i limit to 10,000 rows it works without issue.

So what is causing the problem? Disk space is plenty available.

EDIT:

code:

```
df.write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").save("hdfs://namenode-server:9000/user/myfile.orc")
```

EDIT 2:

or is it disk space after all?

```
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 20082696192 (18.70 GB)
DFS Used: 1665830730 (1.55 GB)
Non DFS Used: 12819447990 (11.94 GB)
DFS Remaining: 4719075328 (4.39 GB)
DFS Used%: 8.29%
DFS Remaining%: 23.50%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Mon May 21 14:31:52 CEST 2018
```

Source file is 1.5 Gb (txt file format) and some data is added to it and then saved as ORC. Maybe that indeed takes more than 4.39 GB space.

Answer (score -1):

Most often this occurs with **parallel recording in the same place** from different pools or from different submitted applications.
For example you submitted your application twice or you use fair scheduler pools in fair fashion.